# Leaked NSString, not sure why is doing it?

Tags: ios, ipad, memory, sdk, memory-leaks

```
        // Allocate a product
        Product *color = [[Product alloc]init];

        // The result set
        char *name = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1);
        NSString *nameStr = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:name];
        char *code = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2);
        NSString *codeStr = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:code];

        color.name = nameStr;
        color.code = codeStr;

        // Release
        [nameStr release];
        [codeStr release];
        [myProducts addObject:color];
        [color release];
```

The profiler shows the leak on each of the lines I'm allocating the string. Not sure what's causing the issue as I'm releasing.

**EDIT: Found the problem. I needed to release the strings on my Product object. Can't believe I missed that...**

Comment: Looks like you should be releasing `color` too at the end there, no?

Comment: Yeah sorry I missed that on the edit, I had the [color release] in my code. The leak occurs with the allocation of the nameStr string and codeStr

Comment: Found the problem. I needed to release the strings on my Product object. Can't believe I missed that...

Comment: @Manual Diaz No synthesized properties? :(

Comment: Yes they were all synthesized. But I wasn't properly releasing them on the model

Comment: @Manuel Diaz if you found the problem, please put it as answer..Not leave the question hanging without an answer..And accept that answer too..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Data Model wasn't releasing on dealloc.